# Create repeated complex HTML structures with Javascript

Tags: java, html

Creating even a single line of HTML using `.createElement() takes a ton of code:

```
      //<h1><a href="/{{slug}}">{{name}}</a></h1>
      var elementHeading = document.createElement("h1");
      elementHeader.appendChild(elementHeading);
        var elementHeadingLink = document.createElement("a");
          var elementHeadingLinkHref = document.createAttribute("href");
            elementHeadingLinkHref.value = '/slug/';
            elementHeadingLink.setAttributeNode(elementHeadingLinkHref); 
          var elementHeadingLinkText = document.createTextNode('name');
        elementHeadingLink.appendChild(elementHeadingLinkText);
      elementHeading.appendChild(elementHeadingLink);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: And what is your Q?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to output the HTML onto the page in the beginning, then use .cloneNode() to create a copy of the element, which you can then modify and add to your document.

```
var elementTemplate = document.getElementById("elementTemplateHolder").firstChild;
var newElement = elementTemplate .cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newElement);
```